Saving pandas DataFrame in a middle of a of a apply loop
When whorking with pandas, it is necessary to use apply or map function. In my case, I have a very long (14 hours) traitement of my data to do and I want to save the DataFrame if any error raise in the middle.
To be mode concrete, consider the following code
import pandas as pd
from math import log

data = pd.DataFrame()
data['x'] = [1,2,-1,4,5]

try:
    data['y'] = data['x'].apply(log)
except Exception as e:
    data.to_pickle('data.pkl')
    raise(e)

When it is executed, it raise a ValueException when trying to compute log(-1). I would like to save my already computed data and the re-raised the Exception.
Unfortunatly this is not working. When you try
data_bis = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')
print(data_bis)

You get only the x column. As far as I understand, first pandas create a new Series with the computed values and then append it to the dataframe.
Do you have any idea how to save already computed data before re-raising the exception ?

maybe better create function which runs log in try/except to catch error.

you would have to run log on every row separately and write all data after every row (or append new row  to CSV). But this makes no sense - better use log in try/except

@furas yes this is one working solution, but I found it 'non pandasic'. It is know that apply and map are faster than iterate thought the rows

so why not write function def my_log(x): try: return log(x) except  ValueError:: return None and later use apply(my_log)

BTW: you should check numpy.log because probably it returns NaN for -1 instead of raising error.

To be clear, I don't want to compute some log, my function is way more complexe than that and my DataFrame have 100k rows. This is a toy example

So Exception can be a lot of things, not just ValueError

solution can be the same: run code in try/except to catch it.

data['x'].apply(log) processes the whole x column before it is assigned to the new column y. So the error will inevitably be raised and y will not be created. It is not a x,y row-wise operation.

BTW: in apply() you can also run code which makes your calculation and which writes result in some other file. But it also needs to use try/except in this function.

@furas the problem is not to catch the exception, the problem is to save computed data.

I think better is to catch exception instead of writing data. And if you need to write it then you can do it inside apply() - something like new code in my answer.

@user19077881 I am reluctant because in a 14 hours apply if there is a problem at the 13th hour it is really a shame.

@user19077881So I can't live with it neither move on.

A mathematical `apply function on a DF column with 100k rows should take less than 0.05 seconds. It is very difficult to imagine what sort of processing function you are using that takes 14 hours or why this cannot be drastically optimized.

@user19077881 imagine a function taking prompt as argument and using a complexe pipeline with some LLMs...

3 to 4 second par row, 50k rows I let you figure it out

I never say it was a mathematical function, the log was a toy example

EDIT:
If you have different function with different Exceptions then solution could be the same - run code in try/except to catch it and replace result with None, numpy.NaN or other value.
EDIT 2:
You can also write data in this function - and append new result to previous reults
def my_log(x):
    try:
        result = math.log(x)
        with open('column_x.csv', 'a') as f:
             f.write( f"{result}\n" )
        return result
    except ValueError:
        return None    


I would rather use math.log in own try/except to catch problem and send None
def my_log(x):
    try:
        return log(x)
    except ValueError:
        return None    

data['y'] = data['x'].apply(my_log)

Or I would use numpy.log() because it returns NaN instead of rasing error:
import numpy as np

data['z'] = data['x'].apply(np.log)


Full working example:
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np

def my_log(x):
    try:
        return math.log(x)
    except ValueError:
        return None    

data = pd.DataFrame()
data['x'] = [1,2,-1,4,5]
    
data['y'] = data['x'].apply(my_log)
data['z'] = data['x'].apply(np.log)

print(data)

Result:
   x         y         z
0  1  0.000000  0.000000
1  2  0.693147  0.693147
2 -1       NaN       NaN
3  4  1.386294  1.386294
4  5  1.609438  1.609438


I am not interrested to compute log this is a toy example. Change 'log' with 'foo()' which can be anything.

And I want to be exhaustif, catch every exception and not write juste 'Nan', re-raise it.

I guess your edit 2, is the closest that one can do. Thanks for the suggestion

Answering my own question.
A bit like the suggestion of @furas but without writing at each step.
import pandas as pd
from math import log

data = pd.DataFrame()
data['x'] = [1,2,3,4,5,-1,4,5]

def my_log(x, t : list):
    z=log(x)
    t.append(z)
    return z

t = []
try:
    data['y'] = data['x'].apply(my_log,t=t)
except Exception as e:
    t_bis = t+['nan' for _ in range(len(data)-len(t))]
    data['y'] = t_bis
    data.to_pickle('data.pkl')
    raise(e)

The idea is to stock intermediate value in a list to create a full dataFrame if an exception is thrown.

if this resolves your problem then you can mark your answer as accepted :) And later you can upvote your answer.

To be honest, I prefer my answer (I haven't try it but I think it will be faster) but your answer is also good so I don't want to un-accepted it. Thanks for your help
